# Как сгенерировать максимальное количество уникальных подсписков из списка

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть список `List<string>`. В нем `1000` неповторяюшихся элементов. Хочу получить  списки из исходного списка, состоящие каждый из `8` элементов, но чтобы ни в одном списке не было больше `5` совпадений из другого массива.

Допустим два списка. Они разные, так как совпадений не более 5.

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,5,13,17,19
```

Как сгенерировать максимальное количество таких списков?

Comment: Во-первых, что значит "из другого массива"? Из предыдущего? Или изо всех предыдущих? Во-вторых, сказано "чтобы не было больше 3 совпадений". Но у вас в примере явно больше 3 совпадений.

Comment: @AnT пардон) сам запутался.. Внёс коррективы

Comment: вы хотите получит все возможные списки?

Comment: Да. В идеале конечно задать сколько мне нужно. Ну в принципе без разницы

Comment: Таких комбинаций будет очень много. Вряд ли получится сгенерировать все возможные варианты.

Answer (score 1):

1. Выбираем уникальные тройки индексов (которые гарантированно не пересекутся с другими тройками) из 1000:

```
{0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, ...
```

их будет 333

2. К каждой такой тройке можно добавить любые 5 элементов из 1000 (которых еще нет в этой тройке)
   Например, тупо через 5 циклов:

```
для каждой тройки из п.1:
{
    for (i = 0; i < 1000 - 4; ++i) {
      for (j = i + 1; j < 1000 - 3; ++j) {
        for (k = j + 1; k < 1000 - 2; ++k) {
          for (m = k + 1; m < 1000 - 1; ++m) {
            for (n = m + 1; n < 1000 - 0; ++n) {
               if (тройка не содержит i,j,k,m,n) {
                  мы получили очередной список индексов размером 8 элементов 
               }
            }     
          }     
        } 
      }
    }
}
```

Это гарантирует условие "ни в одном списке не было больше 5 совпадений".
Но не переберет все варианты. Хотя их будет довольно много, возможно, этого будет достаточно.

Answer (score 1):

Создаём список с тысячей неповторяющихся элементов. Берём первые пять (они гарантированно не совпадают) и удаляем их из списка. Далее проходимся циклом по другим элементам, беря их по три (и тоже удаляем).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            List<string> list = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).Select(n => n.ToString()).ToList();

            foreach (var subList in GetSubLists(list))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", subList));
            }
        }

        static IEnumerable<List<string>> GetSubLists(List<string> list)
        {
            var firstFive = list.Take(5).ToList();
            foreach (var s in firstFive)
            {
                list.Remove(s);
            }

            while (list.Count > 3)
            {
                var nextThree = list.Take(3).ToList();
                foreach (var s in nextThree)
                {
                    list.Remove(s);
                }

                yield return firstFive.Concat(nextThree).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Общее количество таких подсписков оказывается вовсе невелико: 331.
В итоге в списке остаются два неиспользованных элемента.

PS: в данной реализации алгоритма удаление из списка производится с начала - это неэффективно, т. к. весь хвост сдвигается. Правильный было бы брать и удалять элементы с конца.
Можно, конечно, и вообще без удаления обойтись, сдвигая счётчик индекса.